# set grid made by js on the background of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, styles

I try to make paint app in javascript. I need to make square grid and  by pushing button. I made such grid but it is not on the background. How should I pass grid made by js on the background?

```js
function print_grid() 
{
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 5100, 5100);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 5100, 5100);


    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let i = 0; i < 39; i++)
    {
        
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.moveTo(50*i, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(50*i, 5100);
        ctx.moveTo(0, 50*i);
        ctx.lineTo(5100, 50*i);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Board</h1>
    
    <button onclick="print_grid()">square</button>

    <p >draw!!!</p>
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is using two canvases layered on top of each other. This way you can draw the grid onto the background layer independent from the canvas in the foreground.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let coordinates = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

let painting = false;

function getPosition(event) {
  coordinates.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  coordinates.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
}

function startPainting(event) {
  painting = true;
  getPosition(event);
}

function stopPainting() {
  painting = false;
}

function draw(event) {
  if (!painting) return;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.lineCap = 'round';
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.moveTo(coordinates.x, coordinates.y);
  getPosition(event);
  ctx.lineTo(coordinates.x, coordinates.y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function clearCanvas() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function printGrid() {
  let backgroundCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let context = backgroundCanvas.getContext("2d");
  context.beginPath();
  for (let a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    context.moveTo(0, parseInt(a * (backgroundCanvas.height / 9)));
    context.lineTo(backgroundCanvas.width, parseInt(a * (backgroundCanvas.height / 9)));
    context.moveTo(parseInt(a * (backgroundCanvas.width / 9)), 0);
    context.lineTo(parseInt(a * (backgroundCanvas.width / 9)), backgroundCanvas.height);
  }
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath();
}

printGrid();

document.addEventListener('mousedown', startPainting);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPainting);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
```

```html
<button onclick='clearCanvas();'>Clear</button>
<div>
  <canvas id='canvas' style='position: absolute'></canvas>
  <canvas id='canvas2' style='position: absolute'></canvas>
</div>
```